# No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE (has extras) }

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

Why I could receive this crash? I check the report in crittercism and the device affected was a GT-I9300 (Samsung S3) in 4.2.2. It's only one report in about 2500 daily users.

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{co.seahorse.android/co.seahorse.android.views.camera.CameraActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE (has extras) }
```

Comment: i think activity doesn't declared in mainfest.xml could you post your code and mainfest.xml ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This exception is thrown when the phone can't find an activity (application) that can handle your intent. On S3 it shouldn't be the case of no camera application but in very rare occasions things that are supposed to always work just fail.

As long as you don't have more frequent reports I wouldn't worry. I'd say that in 99% of the cases, single time reports are not a problem.

Comment: Note that this sort of problem (starting an activity that theoretically should be there but isn't) will be increasingly more common, as Android 4.3's restricted profiles allows tablet users to limit other accounts' app access. So, the *device* might have a camera app, or a browser, or whatever, but the *user* does not have rights to run it. Hence, it is increasingly important to wrap `startActivity()` calls in a `try`/`catch` block to watch for `ActivityNotFoundException`s and handle them as gracefully as possible.

Comment: That's absolutely true and a good practice. As his report was from a 4.2.2 device it wasn't the case but still worth adding the try/catch.

Comment: CommonsWare, would it still pass resolveActivity() not NULL test if the device is pressent but not accessible for specified account?